# how to add an element in xml file with SubElement

Tags: python, xml

so from 2 days i'm trying to add elements in my xml file, but i still have problem, if some one can help me !!

this my code :

```
tree = etree.parse('Matching_Result.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent="   ",newl="")
for mot in root.findall('mot'): 
     name = mot.get('id')
     rank = mot.find('val').text
     print name , rank
     if name.encode('utf-8') == 'ابْتهَج':
        val = SubElement(mot, 'val')
        newval = 'ابتهج'
        val.text = newval.decode('utf-8')
        with open("Matching_Result.xml", "w") as f:
             f.write(xmlstr.encode('utf-8'))
```

My xml file is like this :

```
<mathing>
   <mot id="شَعر" >    
   <val>شَعُر</val>
   </mot>
   <mot id="ابْتهَج">
    <val></val>
</mot>
</matching>
```

SO I should have an out xml file like :

```
<mathing>
       <mot id="شَعر" >    
       <val>شَعُر</val>
       </mot>
       <mot id="ابْتهَج">
        <val>ابتهج</val>
    </mot>
    </matching>
```

but after exuted my code notheing change in my xml output file !!

Comment: What is the problem with your code??

Comment: I HAVE NOT ANY CHANGE IN MY XML OUTPUT FILE !!

Answer (score 0):

I can see couple of problems with your code and data.

a. Wrong tag `mathing` at start of your xml file
b. etree doesn't have method parse, it should be `ET.parse('Matching_Result.xml)`
c. I thing you can do this without minidom too.

This code is working for me, add encoding-decodings and check.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('Matching_Result.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for mot in root.findall('mot'):
     name = mot.get('id')
     rank = mot.find('val').text
     print name , rank
     if name == 'abc':
         val= mot.find('val')
         val.text = 'new_val'
tree.write('Matching_Result.xml')
```

Initial `Matching_Result.xml` :

```
<matching>
         <mot id="test">
               <val>testing</val>
         </mot>
          <mot id="abc">
              <val></val>
       </mot>
</matching>
```

Final `Matching_Result.xml` :

```
<matching>
         <mot id="test">
               <val>testing</val>
         </mot>
          <mot id="abc">
              <val>new_val</val>
       </mot>
</matching>
```

Comment: yes but why if i change: tree.write('Matching_Result.xml',encoding='utf-8') by : with open("Matching_Result.xml", "w") as f:
                     f.write(xmlstr.encode('utf-8')) by  i will have not any change !!

Comment: Because you haven't made any change to `xmlstr` , you just created a SubElement and haven't modified xmlstr after that.Thus, It won't be reflected in your final result.

Comment: In my solution, I edited my tree object and finally wrote that updated tree to the file.